# Django repeatable field with only new items

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-1.8

I want to create an Instruction that has multiple Steps. A simplified model would look like this:

```
class Step(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Instruction(models.Model):
    steps = models.ForeignKey(Step)
```

The problem is that I want to create a new Instruction with multiple steps, but when I create one in the admin, I should have a **repeatable form field**. For each step I can add a field and create a new Step. **I do not need to be able to select an already existing step.** I'm not sure if there is something OOTB of a package that already does that... Any ideas how to tackle this?

To give an example of what I'm trying to accomplish: the ACF repeater field in WP:
[image]

In my case I would only need a `description` field with the description of the step

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have things a bit backwards. The `ForeignKey` relationship should be the other way around (since an instruction can have many steps, but each step only has one related instruction...a `Many-to-One` relationship).

```
class Step(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    instruction = models.ForeignKey(Instruction, related_name='steps')

class Instruction(models.Model):
    # some fields
```

Now, in your Admin, you can use [inlines](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin) to display these fields in a "repeatable" manner, similar to ACF.